# Redux actions not calling reducers

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, flux

The title of this question pretty much sums it up, I'm calling the actions but it doesn't seem to trigger the reducers. But first! Some code...

index.html:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configurestore from './store/configureStore';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const store  = configurestore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteContact, addContact } from './actions/Contacts';
import ContactList from './components/ContactList';
import ContactAdder from './components/ContactAdder';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <h1>Contacts</h1>

         <ContactList
          contacts={this.props.contacts}
          onDelete={this.props.deleteContact}
        />

         <ContactAdder onAdd={this.props.addContact} />

      </div>
    );
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        contacts: state.contacts
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        deleteContact: () => deleteContact(),
        addContact: (firstName, lastName) => addContact(firstName, lastName)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

store/configureStore.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
}
```

reducers/Contacts.js:

```
export function contacts(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_CONTACT':
            // TODO
            console.log('this is not getting called');
            return state;
        case 'DELETE_CONTACT':
            // TODO
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

reducers/index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { contacts } from './Contacts' ;

export default combineReducers({ contacts });
```

actions/Contacts.js:

```
export function addContact(firstName, lastName) {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_CONTACT',
        contact: {
            fistName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName
        }
    };
}

export function deleteContact(id) {
    return {
        type: 'DELETE_CONTACT',
        id: id
    };
}
```

components/ContactAdder.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from './Input';
import Button from './Button';

class ContactAdder extends Component {

    state = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    };

    onFirstNameChange(val) {
        this.setState({firstName: val.target.value});
    }

    onLastNameChange(val) {
        this.setState({lastName: val.target.value});
    }

    onAdd () {
        this.props.onAdd(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName);
        this.setState({ firstName: '' });
        this.setState({ lastName: '' });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='ContactAdder'>
                <Input type='text' value={this.state.firstName} onChange={(evt) => this.onFirstNameChange(evt)} placeholder='First Name' />
                <Input type='text' value={this.state.lastName} onChange={(evt) => this.onLastNameChange(evt)} placeholder='Last Name' />
                <Button add onClick={this.onAdd.bind(this)}>Add</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default ContactAdder;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not dispatching the actions, you are just calling the action creators as any other regular function, therefore it only returns the object, but it doesn't do anything with it, you need to dispatch that object.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    deleteContact: () => dispatch(deleteContact()),
    addContact: (firstName, lastName) => dispatch(addContact(firstName, lastName))
  };
}

// Don't forget to connect and export
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Just by adding the `dispatch` will fix your problem. Alternative, I personally prefer the following sintaxis to bind the dispatches.

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { deleteContact, addContact}
)(App);
```

The previous code does exactly the same as what you are trying to do.